# Flutter Android license status unknown

Tags: android, flutter, licensing, status

```
$ flutter doctor
```

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3) ✗ Android license status unknown.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3)

✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

[!] VS Code (version 1.31.1)

✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is

- Install java with version > = java 8 and update JAVA_HOME
- $ flutter doctor --android-licenses 
  and enter Y when is asked

It worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

**1.** I run $ **flutter doctor --android-licenses** - It runs SDK manager to accept licenses.

After that, I got some classException that is due to JDK.

**2.** Downloaded and Installed **Java 8**, set **path** to C:\Program Files \Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin.

**Problem solved...**
I got the command from here - [7 Flutter Commands](http://androidride.com/flutter-create-new-project-command-line-options)

Answer (score 1):

Its worked me..

So here the solution, open your SDK manager then uncheck `Hide Obsolete Packages`

Refer--https://robbinespu.gitlab.io/blog/2020/03/03/flutter-issue-fixed-android-license-status-unknown-on-windows/

refer---if needed we can download package manually here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip (for Windows user). Hope this tutorial help people who looking for solution

[image]

Now you’ll see `Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1` appears. Tick that package and hit `apply button` then ok button. it will download sdk.
then `restart` Android studio

Nice, now if you run `flutter doctor`, you should get positive result as below

```
PS D:\Workplace\flutter_projects> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale en-MY)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

PS D:\Workplace\flutter_projects> flutter doctor --android-licenses -v
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and enter Y when is asked

if needed we can download package manually here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip (for Windows user). Hope this tutorial help people who looking for solution

Answer (score 1):

I am using intellij community edition 2021.2 on windows 10. These commands worked for me :

```
 D:\Software\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
 D:\Software\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --update
 D:\Software\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager  --licenses
```

Now run

```
flutter doctor -v
```