# Android license status unknown?

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

For app development I download and installed Flutter sdk along with its dependencies Android studio, Java. After installing all I came to an error
for checking `flutter doctor`. The following error came:

```
    Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
        X Android license status unknown.
          Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
          See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Then after searching with the help of [Flutter Android license status unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143752/flutter-android-license-status-unknown)  I tried to update Android SDK with `PathToAndroidSDK --update` It again generates following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
            at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
            ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the `flutter doctor` command?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.529], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: @leo0boy, have you successfully fix your problem? I have similar issue even if I reinstall everything

Comment: Try to install Java SE 8. Version 11 or 12 don't seem to work, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

Refer : https://robbinespu.gitlab.io/blog/2020/03/02/flutter-issue-android-license-status-unknown-on-windows/

In Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools
 1. Uncheck the "Hide Obsolete Packages"
 2. Select Android SDK Tools(Obsolete) and Apply

After the installation try "flutter doctor" from command prompt.
If some licenses are not accepted then accept by using "flutter doctor --android-licenses"

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the solution how to fix Android licenses status unknown

Firstly, if you are watching this error

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
        X Android license status unknown.
          Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
          See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

then go and uninstall **"Android sdk tool"** and **"Obsolete"** and reinstall.
Then, run the code **"flutter doctor"**
You will see some like this "If some licenses are not accepted then accept by using "flutter doctor --android-licenses"

Then run the code if you got stuck and not be able to reply "y" then goto this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio) and download **Command line tools only**and extract it and put ***sdkmanager file*** in C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin and run cmd in this folder and type ***"sdkmanager --licenses"*** and now you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

After a long night i figured out that i have installed a bad Java version.

I solved this installing JDK 8, correctly and setting the jdk path on android studio.

After that

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Of course the obsolete tools should be installed too

Hope it helps. To some one reaching here.